# How to write email on a link column of Interactive report in oracle apex 5.1

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have created a report in which I have a link column. What I want to do is to send an email to the given id when I click on that link. I have created a dynamic action to send an email which is working fine. But, the problem is I wrote it on **after refresh** that's why it is generating two mails. I want to ask how can I trigger that action when the link is click?

Comment: Check if the option "Fire on Initialization" is set to "NO", if not, set to "NO"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know how is your code to send email, but I suppose that code receive a id number as input and do the work to send the email.

To do this without reload the page follow this steps:

1 - Create an item in your page to store the id to send the email.

2 - On the column of your report that have the link, go to "HTML Expression" and set this code (make the necessary update).

```
<span onclick="$s('P9_MYITEM',#MYID#);">#MYSHOWVALUE#</span>
<!--MYID and MYSHOWVALUE are columns of your select.-->
```

[image]

2a - If you are using a link column, go to "Link Builder Target", select URL as type and put this on "URL" field (make the necessary update):

```
javascript:$s('P9_MYITEM',#MYID#);
```

[image]

3 - Now, just create a dynamic action when change this item, submit this item to get the changed values.

[image]

4 - Do not forget to set to "NO" the option to "Fire on Initialization".

Comment: As I want this action on link type column. So that's why i couldn't find HTML Expression. How can I use it on link type column?

Comment: I set the dynamic action on page load but now I am getting email whenever page is loading. I want to send email when the user click on the link suppose approve, it will perform validation and see if everything ok then it will send the email. I couldn't find the  "Fire on Initialization" option.

Comment: Really sorry, i gave you a wrong answer, i test it and the instructions don't work. I updated the answer and i test it and works

Comment: which version of oracle apex you are using? mine is 5.1.3 and I cannot see many options you are trying to guide me.

Comment: I edit the answer with a image of link builder target